# Reading XML and storing to arrays in PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
print"<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

It printout this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [b] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [c] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [d] => 543
                )

        )

)
```

but when I type `echo $xml["b"]["c"]["d"];` nothing happens

Comment: if you are using PHP5, I suggest you use OO approach of SimpleXML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `print_r` is kind of misleading,
actually the `$xml` is series/array of SimpleXmlElement objects

so

```
echo (int)$xml->b->c->d;  --- type casting is required
```

here is some [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) you should take a look first

Additional to [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php),
because everything node inside the xml object is either `string` or `int`

PHP will auto convert for numeric string to integer,
however, is clearer if you provide the type hinting

```
var_dump($xml); --- you should see more information on the data type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo $xml->b->c->d;`

$xml is not array they are objects.